# in gradle how to include parent project in subproject?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

ProjectA is parent and where ProjecB is subproject or child in hierarchy.

ProjectA

> setting.gralde (include "ProjectB")

Now ProjectB need to instantiate a class of ProjectA. But no success.

I tried in build.gradle of ProjectB

> implementation project(":ProjectA")

Comment: In a normal gradle setup, parent projects won't have any source code (so you won't apply the java plugin to parent projects). Instead, a parent project should just be a logical grouping of child projects (it might apply "common" build logic to it's children). In your example, ProjectA and ProjectB should be siblings, not parent/child